# How to find out if string is only numbers, no letters

Tags: c++

I have constructed a code that checks if the entered number is a proper divisible of 9 by getting the string length and finding the sum of each digit entered and finding if its perfectly divisible by 9.

The code works well, I just need some error checks and I have two things to try and add to it.

I need to make sure first that the inputted information is only numbers, no letters.

Also I want to find a way to make input limited from 1 to 1000.

I have this bool example that will check if it is in fact a number, but how can I make an if statement for my userNum input to check the boolean?

```
bool isNumber(const string &line)
{
    if (line[0] == '0') return true;
    return (atoi(line.c_str()));
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
string userNum;
char userInput;
int sum, i, n;


int main()
{
    tryagain:
    sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter number to test if it is divisible by 9: ";
    cin >> userNum;

    if (userNum == isNumber) {
        cout << "Nah..";
        return 0;

    // Find sum of digits by seperating
    n = userNum.length(); // Gets the sum of the string length in bytes

    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // Starting from 0, until num is less than the length of userNum go up one increment
        sum = (sum + (userNum[i] - '0'));

    if (sum % 9 == 0) {
        cout << "Your number, " << userNum << " adds up to " << sum << " which is evenly divisible to 9" << endl << endl;
    }
    else {

        cout << "Your number, " << userNum << " adds up to " << sum << " which IS NOT evenly divisible to 9" << endl << endl;
    }

    // Restart option begins here.

    cout << "Would you like to try another number? (Y/N): ";
    cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput == 'y' || userInput == 'Y') {
        goto tryagain;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if (userInput == 'n' || userInput == 'N') {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You have entered an unknown input, goodbye!" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use C++11 or above? You could create a regular expression and use `regex_match`

Comment: Why not have `int userNum;` instead of `string userNum;`?

Comment: @Justin because it is a lot harder to strip each singular digit from an integer than simply finding the string.length. Or am I mistaken on that? Basically I take whatever the input is, find the sum of the digits and find if its divisible to 9

Answer (score 4):

You could do this in 3 ways:

1. Use a regular expression, with [std::regex_match](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match). The regex that you are looking for is `^[0-9]+$` which checks if a string contains only numbers. This is a **possible** expression but not the absolute one
2. Use [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which tries to convert a string into an integer. Be sure to surround it with a `try-catch` statement to ensure that the string can be properly parsed. If you get the exception, then the string is not a number.
3. As Justin has pointed out in the comments, you could also try using [std::isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and iterate over the string to check each char.

Rely on `std` functions and try to avoid writing code by yourself. The second approach is probably what you are looking for because, if the method does not throw an exception, you can check the range of the number.

When you face a problem for which you cannot find a solution, give a look at the [list of algorithms on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). Use them as much as you can because they make the code shorter, easier to read and they can give you advantages (**some** algorithms just need an extra parameter at the end to start a parallel execution of the method!)

Comment: Regular expressions seems kind of heavy for this. `std::all_of(string.begin(), string.end(), [](char c) { return std::isdigit(c); })` would be my go-to (maybe not `std::isdigit` because of locale awareness, but roughly that)

Comment: You are right I have forgotten about `std::isdigit`! There are so many std utilities right now... I'm including it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(userNum[i] < '0' || userNum[i] > '9') {
        cout << "Nah..";
        return 0;
    }
    sum = (sum + (userNum[i] - '0'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juan.. This sum < 1 || sum > 1000 works for only 0, but if i enter 1001 it still goes through. Thanks

Comment: Adding an explanation of how/why this code answers the question, rather than just showing the code, would improve the answer.

Comment: I'm really not sure how it fixed the issue I have, but I just thought that there is no reason for the if statement to be embed in the for statement and it'd make more sense if the if statement came before we started our for. Sorry I'm still a rookie at this I'm trying to follow the rules as much as I can!

Comment: if you want to check the string for non alphanumeric characters, one way or another you are going to iterate over the string to check, you can do it before, or you can do it while you do the sum, if you do it before, there is more overhead, but it's more understandable, Performance/Modifiability, do as you please

Comment: i really was not thinking about the 1000 limit, I feel like you are better off parsing the string than doing that other sum thing, you can do it manually or use c++ features

Comment: manually you should iterate backwards and add the digits multiplied by 10 * (iteration number)

Answer (score 0):

Given the necessary range-check with the range being 1...1000, you do not gain anything from summing the digits *and* dividing the sum by 9, instead of just doing the latter on the number itself. So the numerical part could be simple `i < 1`, `i > 1000`, `i % 9 == 0` checks, where `i` is the parsed integer.

[`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) parses a number at the beginning of a string, so while you can use it, it does not replace checking the characters. e.g. `1`, `1.2`, `1a` are all parsed to 1. You need a string which does not start with a number, and only then you get an `std::invalid_argument` exception. So you will need @Justin's suggestion too, though here I flipped it as "`any_of` the characters is `not a digit`:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
try {
    if (std::any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }))
        throw std::invalid_argument(" is not all-digits");
    int i = std::stoi(s);
    if (i < 1) throw std::invalid_argument(" is less than 1");
    if (i > 1000) throw std::invalid_argument(" is more than 1000");
    if (i % 9 == 0) std::cout << i << " is divisible by 9" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << i << " is not divisible by 9" << std::endl;
}
catch (std::invalid_argument ia) {
    std::cout << s << ia.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (std::out_of_range oor) {
    std::cout << s << " sure is not between 1 and 1000";
}
```

(`stoi`'s "own" `invalid_argument` can not occur here, because of the pre-check for all-digits)

---

In the case you would want to get a number between 1 and 10<sup>10000</sup> inclusive, then yes, you could start doing magics, like checking length of input, various patterns, and summing the digits:
(Example is tuned down to 10<sup>10</sup> so it can be tested without getting a headache)

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
std::string::iterator it = s.begin(), end = s.end();
int len = end - it;
try {
    // if(len==0) will not happen because of the cin
    if (*it == '0') {
        if (len == 1) throw std::invalid_argument(" is less than 1");
        throw std::invalid_argument(" starts with 0, multi-digit numbers do not do that");
    }
    if (len > 11) throw std::invalid_argument(" is too long for not being greater than 10^10");
    if (len == 11) {
        if (*it != '1' 
            || std::any_of(it + 1, end, [](char c) { return c != '0'; }))
            throw std::invalid_argument(" is greater than 10^10 or is not all-digits");
        // well, here we know that the number is 10^10 (and is not divisible by 9)
        // so this could return early
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (; it != end; ++it) {
        if(!std::isdigit(*it)) throw std::invalid_argument(" is not all-digits");
        sum += (*it) - '0';
    }
    if (sum % 9 == 0)std::cout << s << " is divisible by 9" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << s << " is not divisible by 9" << std::endl;
}
catch (std::invalid_argument ia) {
    std::cout << s << ia.what() << std::endl;
}
```